# Find basis and calculate dimension of this subspace of R4

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$U = \left\{ (a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid a + b = c + d \right\}$

I'm not sure how to use $a + b = c + d$ to setup the matrix to get to rref.

Comment: To find basis, first you should try to find a system of generator for $U$. Such system is usaully composed off vectors that generates  $U$.

Answer (score 2):

You have one restriction there, so you'll have one variable in terms of the others. Say, $d = a + b -c$. So a generic $(a,b,c,d) \in U$ is actually: $$(a,b,c,d) = (a,b,c,a+b-c) = a(1,0,0,1) + b(0,1,0,1) + c(0,0,1,-1).$$ Can you conclude now?

Answer (score 1):

The equation
$$
a + b = c + d
$$
is equivalent to
$$
a + b - c - d = 0
$$
which is the equation of a hyperplane $U$ with normal vector $(1,1,-1,-1)$:
$$
(1, 1, -1, -1) \cdot (a, b, c, d) = 0
$$